# Do I need a comma or semi-colon before particularly in this example

Tags: grammar

I thoroughly enjoy getting lost in the writing of Donna Tartt, particularly The Secret History.

Comment: comma. just a comma will be enough.

Answer (score 9):

I think a comma is correct. A semicolon would separate two main clauses, but the second part of the sentence is not a main clause (it is not a sentence by itself and has no verb). The comma is used because the second part adds more information on to the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

you do not need a semicolon. remember semicolons cannot be used before a dependent clause only a dependent. Ask yourself if this clause can stand alone as a sentence; this means an independent clause must be a complete thought with a verb and noun.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-colons are only used to join **Two independent clauses.** particularly The Secret History cannot 'stand by itself' if that makes sense.